# IIS web.config file non-existent, website doesnt run html

Tags: iis, web, web-config

I started a webpage yesterday using IIS, and now it doesn't work, error 500.19. It says it is looking for a web.config file, which I added, with a basic skeleton. Predictably, this didn't work. Any ideas from the community of people smarter than me? Thanks a lot for even viewing this question!

Comment: Can you please include your config file in your question

Comment: I don't have a config file, and I don't know how to make one. I assume that's the issue @VictorLeontyev